# Efficiently iterate/submap a TreeMap backwards from a specific postion (key)

Tags: java

What I need is a sub-list of values from a requested key backwards for n entries. Since the maps are really big I want to know if "floorKey" is the most efficient way to get this task done.

Can this code be written faster?

```
        TreeMap qMap = new TreeMap();
        Object key = "startKey";

        for (int i=0; i<2000; i++) {
            key = qMap.floorKey(key);
        }

        // get a collection holding last 2000 history objects at startkey
        Collection neededValues = qMap.subMap(key, "startKey").values();
```

EDIT:

Based on @Thilo's answer I did a quick an drity test and yes his method is faster:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        TreeMap a = new TreeMap();
        for (int i=0; i<5000000; i++) a.put("a"+i, i);

        int i=2000;
        Object dummy;

        System.out.println("start a");
        long start = new Date().getTime();
        NavigableSet keys = (NavigableSet) a.navigableKeySet().headSet("a"+670812); // some random position
        Iterator goBack = keys.descendingIterator();

        while (goBack.hasNext() && i>0) {
            dummy = goBack.next();
            i--;
        }

        System.out.println("run a " + (new Date().getTime() - start));
        System.out.println("start b");

        start = new Date().getTime();
        Object key = "a"+670812;
        for (i=0; i<2000; i++) {
            key = a.floorKey(key);
        }

        Object dummy2 = a.subMap(key, "a" + 670812).values();
        System.out.println("run b " + (new Date().getTime() - start));
    }
```

prints

```
start a
run a 6
start b
run b 7
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get a [NavigableSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/NavigableSet.html) from your `TreeMap`.

Something like (did not try)

```
NavigableSet<T> keys = qMap.navigableKeySet().headSet("startKey");
Iterator<T> goBack = keys.descendingIterator();
```

Not sure if it makes a big difference in performance. At least it seems to get rid of your 2000 calls to floorKey.

Comment: please not that you have to cast the keyset  `NavigableSet keys = (NavigableSet) a.navigableKeySet().headSet("startKey");` And headSet does not contain the requested key itself you you have to add them manually (which is no problem since you have to request them anyway).

Comment: Did you find out if this is more efficient than your original method?